# What is the highest number of consecutive identical prime gaps?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Until now, I've only seen up to 3 consecutive identical prime gaps such as $6,6,6$ and $12,12,12$ and so on. Is this the highest number of consecutive identical prime gaps or can it go higher than that?

Comment: If we include sufficient many small prime factors in the difference, we should be able to reach an arbitary number of such gaps. Green Tao's theorem does not quite cover this since it is not about consecutive prime numbers.

Comment: I would love to see at least an example of 4 consecutive identical primes.

Comment: [Consecutive Primes in Arithmetic Progression](http://primerecords.dk/cpap.htm). The longest known sequence is $10$ primes ($9$ gaps).

Comment: @nickgard $10$ primes is an indication that there is no limit in principle. I guess this is an open problem, right ?

Comment: @Peter Yes. I think it's conjectured that there is no limit, but it is an open problem as far as I know. Extending the known record even to $11$ primes is extremely difficult. The minimum required common gap jumps from $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7=210$ to $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot11=2310$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but 224584605939537911 + 81292139 *23# *n is prime for $0 \leq n \leq 26$.

Comment: see http://primerecords.dk/aprecords.htm

Comment: @Houston You miss that the primes in the arithmetic progression have to be consecutive. Nevertheless, an amazing arithmetic progression ! I wonder how it could be found.